# Alternative to RDLC files

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, rdlc

I have an application that uses .rdlc files to present data. The actual report documents are created in the application, and the data is always a single record (albeit from a fairly complex dataset), and there is never a need to manipulate the data once the report has been created. The reports are saved as PDFs so they can be reviewed and shared with customers.

The original application has been written in VS 2008, using the .NET 3.5 Framework; I have to upgrade to 4.7.2 but upgrading these reports seems way more painful than it should be.

My progress so far has been to create a new MVC solution, add the original Webforms pages to the project and linking back to those pages from the new development. I have added a Report project that I (currently) plan on using to create the reports in an effort to separate concerns, but I'm wondering if there is a decent alternative to this approach?